# How do I pass a Java object as a parameter to a MATLAB function?

Tags: java, matlab

I wrote a Matlab class to implement a database using JDBC and stuff from java.sql.

I need to know how many results were in a ResultSet, so I wrote the following Matlab static function:

```
methods (Static)

    function [numRecords] = numRecords(resultSet)
        numRecords = 0;
        if (~isempty(resultSet))
            row = resultSet.getRow();
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
            resultSet.last();
            numRecords = resultSet.getRow();
            resultSet.absolute(row);
        end
    end

end
```

But when I try to call it, I get the following error message:

??? Undefined function or method 'numRecords' for input arguments of type 'org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet40'

There are no other functions called numRecords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing the original question, I realized my error.

Apparently, in a Matlab class, calling a static function requires the enclosing class to be prepended to the function...even when called from within the same class!

I replaced the line:

```
trials = zeros(numRecords(rs));
```

with

```
trials = zeros(CMAPSigSimResultsDB.numRecords(rs));
```

and it worked.  (Well it didn't, but it called the function at least.)

It's a confusing error message, because Matlab isn't supposed to be typed, but it makes it sound like it is...

Comment: @Jim, that often happens when you tell your problem to Darth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612537/why-is-it-that-properly-formulating-your-question-for-stackoverflow-often-yield/612555#612555

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to treat a Java object in MATLAB just like any other variable/object. You can create a Java object like this:

```
myDate = java.util.Date;
```

and then pass that object to a function:

```
myFcn(myDate,...other input arguments...);
```

For more info, you can check out the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4873.html).

**EDIT:**

It may go without saying, but you should avoid giving the function **myFcn** the same name as any of the methods for the Java object you are passing in (i.e. *overloading*). Things can get confusing with respect to which overloaded function actually gets called, as illustrated by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656014/how-to-avoid-ambiguity-when-calling-java-from-matlab) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656014/how-to-avoid-ambiguity-when-calling-java-from-matlab/656315#656315) to it.

Comment: Thanks.. Now I've posted a tweet pointing the questioner's back to this question!